How to invert axis using Seaborn objects interface?
Using the standard Seaborn API, one could invert the X-axis like so,
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data = pd.DataFrame({'values': range(0, 100)})
g = sns.lineplot(data, x='values', y='values')
g.invert_xaxis()

Producing the following output with descending X-values,

How can the following Seaborn objects API example be modified to produce the same output?,
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.objects as so
data = pd.DataFrame({'values': range(0, 100)})
(
    so.Plot(data, x='values', y='values')
    .add(so.Line())
)

